# Reduce the DPI of pdf stream in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, devexpress

I have a PDF document with an image. And tried to preview it using **PdfDocumentProcessor** from DevExpress. But due to memory constraints want to reduce the DPI value of this pdf stream. So is there any possibility to do that?

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var processor = new PdfDocumentProcessor();
    var newDocument = new MemoryStream();

    for (int i = 10; i <= 19; i++)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead($"D:\\Office\\photos\\BigPDF\\{i}.pdf"))
        {
            processor.AppendDocument(stream);
            processor.SaveDocument(newDocument);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only control the DPI when printing, not when saving a local file.

You can however tweak the images within the PDF to convert them to JPEG and change the file quality of those.

See:

- [PdfGraphics.ConvertImagesToJpeg property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressPdfPdfGraphics_ConvertImagesToJpegtopic)
- [JpegImageQuality property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpressPdfPdfGraphics_JpegImageQualitytopic.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Brendon. Could you please help me to control Dpi value when saving?

Comment: It's not possible with the DevExpress PdfDocumentProcessor.